# Is it possible to connect 2016 Report Builder to a SharePoint Online List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, reporting-services

I would like to connect 2016 Report Builder to a SharePoint Online list. Is this possible? I've seen examples with Report Builder being connected to SharePoint on premise but not to SharePoint Online. I know I wont be able to integrate the reports into SharePoint online without using 3rd party software. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to connect 2016 Report Builder to a SharePoint Online list. Please check following link with all available features in SharePoint online:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-service-description.aspx

I think that the best option to build reports is Excel Services or Power BI.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ThorApps ListSync Service to replicate in realtime sharepoint list items into a sql database for reporting purposes.
You can also use ThorApps BI Service to host your ssrs reports in SharePoint Online. 
Www.thorapps.com
Adrian